# i have to display all records with age>30 from csv file, its displaying the records more than 1 time. how to avoid that

Tags: python, function, csv

its displaying the records more than 1 time. how to avoid that

```
import os

import csv

def dispcond():

    f=open('csv2.csv','r')
    empdata=csv.reader(f)
  
    rec=[]
    l=[]
    for i in empdata:
        rec.append(i)
        for j in range(1,len(rec)):
            print(j)
        
    f.close()
dispcond()
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a list. Your file is already a list of lines.

```
import csv

def dispcond():

    with open('csv2.csv','r') as f
        empdata=csv.reader(f)
  
        for line in empdata:
            age = int(line[1])  # the second column, for example
            if age > 30:
                print(age)
```

For CSV data, it is [more common to use Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/10min.html)

Comment: its giving a value error

Comment: Do your csv columns actually have numbers? For example, does your csv file have a header you need to skip?

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import csv

def dispcond():
    f=open('csv2.csv','r')
    empdata=csv.reader(f)
    rec=[]
for i in empdata:
    rec.append(i)
for j in range(1,len(rec)):
    if int(rec[j][1])>30:
        print(rec[j])
f.close()
dispcond()
```

Comment: As mentioned, you do not need rec list

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.